# data must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' R

Tags: r

I am getting this error message:

```
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

The error message comes when i try to run this line:

> dcc.fit = dccfit(spec1, data = r_t1, fit.control=list(scale=TRUE))

However, when i run the line below it works fine:

```
dcc.fit1 = dccfit(spec2, data = r_t1, fit.control=list(scale=TRUE), solver = "nlminb")
```

If there is a problem with the vector r_t1 the code line above shouldn't work either, so this is very strange. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Multivariate3 is an excel file i have imported into R.

[Multivariate3 excel file attached here](https://ufile.io/05sgs)

```
  > head(spec2)
Error in x[seq_len(n)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

My whole code is presented here:

```
install.packages('rmgarch', dependencies = TRUE)
library("rmgarch")
library("parallel")
library("quantmod")

Dat<-data.frame(Multivariate3$Bitcoin,Multivariate3$SP500,Multivariate3$DAX,Multivariate3$KS11,Multivariate3$VGLT,Multivariate3$Euro,Multivariate3$Franc,Multivariate3$Yen,Multivariate3$Oil,Multivariate3$Gold)

#Returns
retBTC<-diff(log(Multivariate3$Bitcoin))
retSP<-diff(log(Multivariate3$SP500))
retDAX<-diff(log(Multivariate3$DAX))
retKS11<-diff(log(Multivariate3$KS11))
retVGLT<-diff(log(Multivariate3$VGLT))
retEUR<-diff(log(Multivariate3$Euro))
retCFH<-diff(log(Multivariate3$Franc))
retYEN<-diff(log(Multivariate3$Yen))
retOil<-diff(log(Multivariate3$Oil))
retGLD<-diff(log(Multivariate3$Gold))

# univariate normal GARCH(1,1) for each series
####UNRESTRICTED MODEL#####
xspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = 'sGARCH'), distribution.model = 'std')
####RESTRICTED MODEL#####
xspec1 = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = 'sGARCH'), distribution.model = 'std',fixed.pars=list(alpha1 = 0, beta1 = 0))

#################################
uspec = multispec(replicate(10, xspec))
uspecx = multispec(replicate(10, xspec1))
spec1 = dccspec(uspec = uspec, dccOrder = c(1, 1), distribution = 'mvnorm')
spec2 = dccspec(uspec = uspecx, dccOrder = c(1, 1), distribution = 'mvnorm')

#return vector
r_t1=cbind(retBTC,retSP,retDAX,retKS11,retVGLT,retEUR,retCFH,retYEN,retOil,retGLD)
####URESTRICTED MODEL#####
dcc.fit = dccfit(spec1, data = r_t1, fit.control=list(scale=TRUE))
####RESTRICTED MODEL#####
dcc.fit1 = dccfit(spec2, data = r_t1, fit.control=list(scale=TRUE), solver = "nlminb")
```

Comment: can you show multivariate3 data?

Comment: Hi Priyanka. 
The multivariate3 excel file is attached to the question now

Comment: Can you add this line `head(spec2)` just above the `#return vector` line and add the output to the question?

Comment: Hi, Hackerman. I have now added the output below the link for the attached file.

Comment: For some reason it worked when i increased the number of observations in the excel file to 313 observations. instead of the original 176. I think it could have be some constraints in the package that i used. If someone finds out why i couldn't have 176 observations in the data, i'd be happy to know why.

Comment: I also had to add a solver.control to the dcc.fit line.

`ctrl = list(tol = 1e-17, delta = 1e-10)` and then:
`dcc.fit = dccfit(spec1, data = r_t1, solver.control = ctrl, fit.control=list(scale=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

I happened to encounter the same error when using `cgarchfit` and I had to pass the `fit.control = list(eval.se = FALSE)` to get rid of the `'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'` error.